# How to show or hide the data based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

In my angular application I have a dropdown list and below that some data is in div.

**component.html**

```html
<select class="form-control" id="power" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select a category</option>
  <option *ngFor="let category of categoryNames">{{ category }}</option>
</select>

<!--below code I have to show or hide-->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <p>Slect Habits</p>
    <h5 class="formxp">Slect Items</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p>Slect Habits</p>
    <h5 class="formxp">Slect Items</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

So my requirement is when I click on any of the items from the dropdown list I have to show the div (after the dropdown in above code)

Can anyone help me regarding the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a template variable (e.g. #mySelect) on the `<select>` element, then use it to determine the selected value: `mySelect.value`.

In case you need to display the div if the selected category equals to 'Habit', you can try the following:

```html
<!-- #mySelect is declared on <select> element -->
<select class="form-control" id="power" required #mySelect>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select a category</option>
  <option *ngFor="let category of categoryNames">{{ category }}</option>
</select>

<div class="row" *ngIf="mySelect.value === 'Habits'">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <p>Slect Habits</p>
    <h5 class="formxp">Slect Items</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p>Slect Habits</p>
    <h5 class="formxp">Slect Items</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about the **Angular Template Variable** here:
https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables

Comment: Thanks @Amer, but from where we can use Habits and mySelect,could you please add that in above code

Comment: I already did that, see the first line please.

Comment: 'Habits' is just an example since I don't know what are your options exactly.